# Chrome/YouTube using motion interpolation; How can I turn it off?

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

Recently I have noticed that when watching YouTube on Chrome, the video is [motion interpolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_interpolation) (the "soap opera" effect). When I watch the same video on Firefox using the Flash plugin there is no motion interpolation. Here is an example video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3d5NQojLZA

After doing some research I found out the reason for this. Chrome/Google recently activate a program they call "[Project Butter](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2015/11/smoother-in-chrome.html)".

I find motion interpolation extremely obnoxious. Is there a way to turn it off? (ideally without using cookies, not psyched about Google tracking me either, which has gotten really creepy recently)

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to some youtube videos playing in 60fps, try clicking settings on the video and selecting one that doesn't have 60fps. I think butter was something for Android

Comment: OP states that other browsers aren't affected, so it's not a matter of framerate.